# How to find asymptotic form of polynomial function?

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, laplace-method

The polynomial function is $$R_n(x)=\sum_{p=2}^{n+1}\frac{(p-1)(2n-p)!}{n!(n+1-p)!}x^p$$

It says the following:

> For large $n$, the asymptotic form of $R_n(1/\beta)$ can be obtained by looking at the values of $p$ which dominate the sum
>
> - $p$ of order $1$ for $\beta > 1/2$,
> - $p$ of order $\sqrt n$ for $\beta = 1/2$, and
> - $p \approx (1 - 2\beta)/(1-\beta)n$ for $\beta < 1/2$

Then how to find the asymptotic solution?

[image: See This Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\beta = 1/x > 0$. Let $p = 2 + n u$, then
$$\frac {(p - 1) (2 n - p)!} {n! (n + 1 - p)!} \beta^{-p} \sim
f(u) e^{n \phi(u)},
\quad n \to \infty, \\
f(u) = \frac u {\beta^2} \sqrt {\frac {1 - u} {2 \pi n (2 - u)^3}}, \\
\phi(u) = -u \ln \beta - (1 - u) \ln(1 - u) + (2 - u) \ln(2 - u).$$
The maximum of $\phi(u)$ is located at $u_0 = (2 \beta - 1)/(\beta - 1)$, which is inside the interval $(0, 1)$ when $\beta < 1/2$. Then the sum is asymptotically equivalent to the corresponding integral and, by Laplace's method, the integral is a.e. to
$$n f(u_0) \int_{\mathbb R} e^{n (\phi(u_0) + \phi''(u_0) u^2/2)} du =
(1 - 2 \beta) (\beta (1 - \beta))^{-n - 1}.$$
If $\beta > 1/2$, the maximum is at the left endpoint and the sum is not a.e. to the corresponding integral. Instead, since we're interested only in small values of $p$, we can replace the summand with its approximation for fixed $p$:
$$\frac {(p - 1) (2 n - p)!} {n! (n + 1 - p)!} \beta^{-p} \sim
\frac {(p - 1) 2^{2 n - p}} {\beta^p \sqrt {\pi n^3}},
\quad n \to \infty.$$
The sum of the remainder is asymptotically smaller, and the original sum is a.e. to
$$\sum_{p \geq 2} \frac {(p - 1) 2^{2 n - p}} {\beta^p \sqrt {\pi n^3}} =
\frac {2^{2 n}} {(2 \beta - 1)^2 \sqrt {\pi n^3}}.$$

Comment: Using Stirling's Approximation ($n!=\sqrt {2\pi n} \Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n$), the form of $f(u)$ I am getting is different! I am getting $$f(u)=\frac{u}{\beta^2}\sqrt\frac{2-u}{2\pi n(1-u)}$$

Comment: $(2 n - p)! \sim ((2 - u) n)!/((2 - u) n)^2$, and $((2 - u) n)!$ gives a $((2 - u) n)^{(2 - u) n + 1/2}$ factor. This leaves $(2 - u)^{-3/2}$.

Comment: also can you elaborate on $\beta > 1/2$ part.

Comment: For the last sum (from $2$ to infinity), you need to estimate the sum from $n + 2$ to infinity and show it is negligible. For the $(p - 1) 2^{2n} (2 \beta)^{-p}/\sqrt{\pi n^3}$ approximation, you need to estimate the remainder uniformly in $p$ and show its sum is negligible.