# find an asymptotic function

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

giving $f(n)= \sum_{t=1}^n {2(t-1) \choose n-1}$
we need to find a function $g(n)$ such that $f(n)=\theta (g(n))$

I tried with Stirling's approximation but i succeed to find only upper bound which is $\sqrt{n}4^n$.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @Jyerkimenon $f(n) \leq \sum_{t=1}^n {2(n-1) \choose n-1} = (n-1) {2(n-1) \choose n-1}$ we know from Stirling's approximation that ${2n\choose n}= \theta(\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n}})$ so $f(n) \leq c(n-1)(\frac{4^n-1}{\sqrt{n-1}}) = c \sqrt{n-1}4^{n-1}\leq c\sqrt{n}4^n$

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A014300](https://oeis.org/A014300) which has "a(n) ~ 4^n / (3*sqrt(Pi*n)). - Vaclav Kotesovec, Oct 25 2017"

Comment: You can find an asymptotically equivalent expression in the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3251248). If $t = n + 1 - t$, the maximum of the summand is at the left endpoint. If you take Stirling's approximation for large $n$ and fixed $t$, the sum of the resulting expression over $t$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is a.e. to the original sum.